# Dynamically import a package from a directory

Tags: python

I am making a server that listens on a socket. Whenever a new request comes in, the server spawns a new instance of handle_request. Each instance of handle_request.py **imports the relevant handler** from request_handlers.

```
server.py
handle_request.py
request_handlers
|_handler_beta
|_handler_1
|_handler_2
```

**While handlerX is a module, request_handlers is not a package**. The modules are self-contained and reloaded on each request. The modules may be added, modified or dropped while the program is running.

---

**Question**: What is the way to import a module from an arbitrary directory?

---

Doing my homework, I saw that most questions deal with **packages**, even one is titled "*python: import a module from a folder*". Hence I believe this question is distinct. The architecture has been simplified; and yes, I am considering pre-forking with reload on file modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `__init__.py` in the directory. That makes it a package. If you're scanning the directory for .py files, you'll probably then want to skip `__init__.py`.

Then, you can import them with `__import__('request_handlers.' + module, fromlist=[''])` (the fromlist is important, otherwise you'll get `request_handlers` rather than the appropriate module).

One way of doing it without an `__init__.py` would be to put the `request_handlers` directory in `sys.path`, but that then makes name clashes with other modules possible. Another way would be with `execfile`. You can research that more if you want to. I'd do it (and have done it before) the package/__import__ way.

Comment: I did try __import__('request_handlers.default_handler', fromlist=['']) which imports default_handler, but NONE of its attributes

Comment: What do you mean, "NONE of its attributes"? You get the module object which has anything in the module.

Comment: >>> import request_handlers.default_handler as dh
>>> dir(dh)
['__ builtins__', '__ doc__', '__ file__', '__ name__', '__ package__', '__ path__']

Answer (score 0):

As Chris said: add an `__init__.py` to your folder. You can use the `__import__()` function if you do not know the names beforehand or if you do not want to have their names fixed in your code.